# iOS Change UITableView header height when scroll swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

how i change my tableview header height when i scroll for example in certain offset?
this is my header implementation, i use custom cell as header. 
But basically what i'm trying to do is show and hide the header when the scroll in certain offset.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let  cell = tableView.dequeueReusableHeaderFooterViewWithIdentifier("tableViewHeader") as! MyTableViewHeaderCell
    return cell
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 70
}

func scrollViewWillBeginDragging(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    if (scrollView.contentOffset.y>400){
  // i want to try to change the height of header to be 0/hidden
}
```

Comment: what should happen when user and/or table stops scrolling?

Comment: hi @ddb depends on the offset i just want to show when the offset is > 400 and hide when the offset<400, for example

Answer (score 0):

I would do like this to handle header height

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    if (myScrollView.contentOffset.y>400){
        return 70
    } else {
        return 0
    }
}
```

and this to manage table view's header update

```
func scrollViewWillBeginDragging(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    if (scrollView.contentOffset.y>400 && itWasLessThan400 == true) {
        itWasLessThan400 = false
        myTableView.reloadData() //or reload only the needed section if you have more than one sections
    } else if (scrollView.contentOffset.y<400 && itWasLessThan400 == false) {
        itWasLessThan400 = true
        myTableView.reloadData() //or reload only the needed section if you have more than one sections
    } else 
}
```

and keep sure to set `itWasLessThan400 = true` at `viewDidLoad` in your viewController

I hope this helps :)